# PutLifecycleHook events not showing up?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-auto-scaling, amazon-cloudtrail

I have an autoscaling group with lifecycle hooks for autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_LAUNCHING and autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_TERMINATING.

I have EventBridge configured to watch for those events and as I understand it they are supposed to go to CloudTrail.  The problem is that even watching CloudTrail directly I don't seem to get near as many PutLifecycle events as it seems like I should.

Testing method:

- create ASG with hooks as above
- wait for it to stabilize
- bump up 'desired capacity'
- new member instance created
- wait for event to show up in CloudTrail.  Sometimes it shows up, sometimes not.
- decrement 'desired capacity'.
- new member instance terminates.
- wait for event to show up in CloudTrail.  Sometimes it shows up, sometimes not.

This *almost* feels like an IAM problem, but even doing all the above as full admin the results are spotty.

I've also tried the ASG -> SNS -> SQS route and gotten similar results.

Is there something in the guts of ASG events I'm not understanding?  Is there somewhere else I should be looking?

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out the events don't go anywhere but the event bus.

The PutLifecycleHook events I was seeing in CloudTrail were actually from me tweaking the lifecycle hook section of the ASG page.  It's a notification that someone changed the lifecycle hook config, not that an actual lifecycle event happened.

To see the events I had to create a log group and then set up a rule with a cloudwatch target.